# disable open_base_dir restriction in plesk for EVERY subdomain

Tags: apache-2.2, php

I have an open_base_dir restriction in affect on my server. I can disable this by adding a vhost.conf file to each domain but I need a way to stop this happening by default.

My php.ini file is set to open_base_dir = none

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to get this working using the following advice:

http://www.hosting.com/support/plesk/removeopenbasedir